# Offline Evernote Access in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, evernote, offline

Is there a way to access my [Evernote](http://evernote.com/) notes offline in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the anser is no.
For offline access Evernote provides a client application (Mac/Windows).
It provides extra features (i.e. screen capture, drag and drop etc.)
Why would you want to use Chrome to access it offline?

Comment: Two reasons actually: I use Linux (and I refuse to use nevernote), and I have a Cr-48. In addition, I always ***always*** have Chrome open, even when I'm not connected to the Internet.